# Why does Google analytics api return "zero"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So,
    I had a website, lets say xxxx.com, I later changed it to yyyy.com

When I did that, I changed the default url in the "admin" section of analytics and also put the old code of xxxx.com into the yyyy.com

So, its tracking perfectly and I also have the old data and its tracking the new data as well.

Now, when I test with google analytics api, if i check users/page views, the value returned is "zero"

I have all the settings the way these should be, I am using a third party built API, which works on my other analytics properties, so the tool works properly. It just doesnt work on this particular yyyy.com and returns value as "zero"

Why so ?

P.S - All the settings in Admin panel of analytics point to the new url. I just dont know where are things going wrong.

Comment: What is the actual query you're running?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to know what could be the reason the analytics api returns "0" as users and pageviews and not the actual data ?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is the actual API query you are running?

Comment: Philip, can i have your email please ?

Comment: I'm not going to post my email here. I also don't answer individual questions because keeping that knowledge in private threads doesn't help the community. If you have additional questions, expand on what you've written above.